# Invalid xml with ssml in C#

Tags: c#, xml, ssml

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how the xml is invalid for my ssml code within C#.

Here is the line of code in C#:

```
  synth.SpeakSsml("<speak version=\"1.0\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis\" xml:lang=\"en-US\">< voice gender=\"male\" age=\"15\" xml:lang=\"en-US\"><prosody contour=\"(0%,+20Hz) (25%,+20Hz) (50%,+20Hz) (75%,+20Hz)\" volume=\"100\">" + say + "</prosody></voice></speak>");
```

and the ssml:

```
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US">
    < voice gender="male" age="15" xml:lang="en-US">
        <prosody contour="(0%,+20Hz) (25%,+20Hz) (50%,+20Hz) (75%,+20Hz)" volume="100">
              Text

    </prosody></voice></speak>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! there is a space in the voice tag!

Comment: Select this as answer. It would be useful to others as well.